How do I return all models in a relation
So, I have a "noms" relation in provider model, i want, if role is manager, to return all models from noms.
I have this:
     {
         return $this->hasMany(Nom::class);
     }

want something like:
     {
         if($this->role === "manager"){
             return Nom::all
         }
         return $this->hasMany(Nom::class);
     }


So, I haven't found the direct answer online, and all your 'just make separate relations' solution is not applicable in my solution (I don't want to edit all pages that have that logic manually). So then I just made a new, Conditional Relation. It just uses a Callable to filter Collection. Here is the code for those who need it:
Trait file, to add to your model class:
<?php

namespace App\Relations;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait HasCustomRelationships{

    public function toIf($related, $condition, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
    {
        $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);

        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

        $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

        return $this->newIf($instance->newQuery(), $this, $condition, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey);
    }

    protected function newIf(Builder $query, Model $parent, $condition, $foreignKey, $localKey)
    {
        return new IfRelation($query, $parent, $condition, $foreignKey, $localKey);
    }

    protected function newRelatedInstance($class)
    {
        return tap(new $class, function ($instance) {
            if (! $instance->getConnectionName()) {
                $instance->setConnection($this->connection);
            }
        });
    }
}

Relation file:
<?php

namespace App\Relations;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Concerns\InteractsWithDictionary;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
use Illuminate\Database\UniqueConstraintViolationException;

class IfRelation extends Relation
{
    use InteractsWithDictionary;

    /**
     * The foreign key of the parent model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $foreignKey;

    /**
     * The local key of the parent model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $localKey;

    /**
     * Condition for relations.
     *
     * @var Callable
     */
    protected $condition;

    /**
     * Create a new has one or many relationship instance.
     *
     * @param Builder $query
     * @param Model $parent
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Builder $query, Model $parent, Callable $condition, $foreignKey, $localKey)
    {
        $this->localKey = $localKey;
        $this->foreignKey = $foreignKey;
        $this->condition = $condition;

        parent::__construct($query, $parent);
    }

    /**
     * Create and return an un-saved instance of the related model.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return Model
     */
    public function make(array $attributes = [])
    {
        return tap($this->related->newInstance($attributes), function ($instance) {
            $this->setForeignAttributesForCreate($instance);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create and return an un-saved instance of the related models.
     *
     * @param  iterable  $records
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function makeMany($records)
    {
        $instances = $this->related->newCollection();

        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $instances->push($this->make($record));
        }

        return $instances;
    }

    /**
     * Set the base constraints on the relation query.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function addConstraints()
    {
        if (static::$constraints) {
            $query = $this->getRelationQuery();
            call_user_func($this->condition,$this->parent,$query);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the constraints for an eager load of the relation.
     *
     * @param  array  $models
     * @return void
     */
    public function addEagerConstraints(array $models){}


    /**
     * Get the value of a relationship by one or many type.
     *
     * @param  array  $dictionary
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  string  $type
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getRelationValue(array $dictionary, $key, $type)
    {
        $value = $dictionary[$key];

        return $type === 'one' ? reset($value) : $this->related->newCollection($value);
    }

    /**
     * Find a model by its primary key or return a new instance of the related model.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $id
     * @param  array  $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection|Model
     */
    public function findOrNew($id, $columns = ['*'])
    {
        if (is_null($instance = $this->find($id, $columns))) {
            $instance = $this->related->newInstance();

            $this->setForeignAttributesForCreate($instance);
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Get the first related model record matching the attributes or instantiate it.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @param  array  $values
     * @return Model
     */
    public function firstOrNew(array $attributes = [], array $values = [])
    {
        if (is_null($instance = $this->where($attributes)->first())) {
            $instance = $this->related->newInstance(array_merge($attributes, $values));

            $this->setForeignAttributesForCreate($instance);
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Get the first record matching the attributes. If the record is not found, create it.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @param  array  $values
     * @return Model
     */
    public function firstOrCreate(array $attributes = [], array $values = [])
    {
        if (is_null($instance = (clone $this)->where($attributes)->first())) {
            $instance = $this->createOrFirst($attributes, $values);
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to create the record. If a unique constraint violation occurs, attempt to find the matching record.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @param  array  $values
     * @return Model
     */
    public function createOrFirst(array $attributes = [], array $values = [])
    {
        try {
            return $this->getQuery()->withSavepointIfNeeded(fn () => $this->create(array_merge($attributes, $values)));
        } catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
            return $this->useWritePdo()->where($attributes)->first() ?? throw $e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create or update a related record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @param  array  $values
     * @return Model
     */
    public function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
    {
        return tap($this->firstOrCreate($attributes, $values), function ($instance) use ($values) {
            if (! $instance->wasRecentlyCreated) {
                $instance->fill($values)->save();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Attach a model instance to the parent model.
     *
     * @param Model $model
     * @return Model|false
     */
    public function save(Model $model)
    {
        $this->setForeignAttributesForCreate($model);

        return $model->save() ? $model : false;
    }

    /**
     * Attach a model instance without raising any events to the parent model.
     *
     * @param Model $model
     * @return Model|false
     */
    public function saveQuietly(Model $model)
    {
        return Model::withoutEvents(function () use ($model) {
            return $this->save($model);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Attach a collection of models to the parent instance.
     *
     * @param  iterable  $models
     * @return iterable
     */
    public function saveMany($models)
    {
        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $this->save($model);
        }

        return $models;
    }

    /**
     * Attach a collection of models to the parent instance without raising any events to the parent model.
     *
     * @param  iterable  $models
     * @return iterable
     */
    public function saveManyQuietly($models)
    {
        return Model::withoutEvents(function () use ($models) {
            return $this->saveMany($models);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of the related model.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return Model
     */
    public function create(array $attributes = [])
    {
        return tap($this->related->newInstance($attributes), function ($instance) {
            $this->setForeignAttributesForCreate($instance);

            $instance->save();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of the related model without raising any events to the parent model.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return Model
     */
    public function createQuietly(array $attributes = [])
    {
        return Model::withoutEvents(fn () => $this->create($attributes));
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of the related model. Allow mass-assignment.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return Model
     */
    public function forceCreate(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $attributes[$this->getForeignKeyName()] = $this->getParentKey();

        return $this->related->forceCreate($attributes);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of the related model with mass assignment without raising model events.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return Model
     */
    public function forceCreateQuietly(array $attributes = [])
    {
        return Model::withoutEvents(fn () => $this->forceCreate($attributes));
    }

    /**
     * Create a Collection of new instances of the related model.
     *
     * @param  iterable  $records
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function createMany(iterable $records)
    {
        $instances = $this->related->newCollection();

        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $instances->push($this->create($record));
        }

        return $instances;
    }

    /**
     * Create a Collection of new instances of the related model without raising any events to the parent model.
     *
     * @param  iterable  $records
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function createManyQuietly(iterable $records)
    {
        return Model::withoutEvents(fn () => $this->createMany($records));
    }

    /**
     * Set the foreign ID for creating a related model.
     *
     * @param Model $model
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setForeignAttributesForCreate(Model $model)
    {
        $model->setAttribute($this->getForeignKeyName(), $this->getParentKey());
    }

    /**
     * Add the constraints for a relationship query.
     *
     * @param Builder $query
     * @param Builder $parentQuery
     * @param  array|mixed  $columns
     * @return Builder
     */
    public function getRelationExistenceQuery(Builder $query, Builder $parentQuery, $columns = ['*'])
    {
        if ($query->getQuery()->from == $parentQuery->getQuery()->from) {
            return $this->getRelationExistenceQueryForSelfRelation($query, $parentQuery, $columns);
        }

        return parent::getRelationExistenceQuery($query, $parentQuery, $columns);
    }

    /**
     * Add the constraints for a relationship query on the same table.
     *
     * @param Builder $query
     * @param Builder $parentQuery
     * @param  array|mixed  $columns
     * @return Builder
     */
    public function getRelationExistenceQueryForSelfRelation(Builder $query, Builder $parentQuery, $columns = ['*'])
    {
        $query->from($query->getModel()->getTable().' as '.$hash = $this->getRelationCountHash());

        $query->getModel()->setTable($hash);

        return $query->select($columns)->whereColumn(
            $this->getQualifiedParentKeyName(), '=', $hash.'.'.$this->getForeignKeyName()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the key for comparing against the parent key in "has" query.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExistenceCompareKey()
    {
        return $this->getQualifiedForeignKeyName();
    }

    /**
     * Get the key value of the parent's local key.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getParentKey()
    {
        return $this->parent->getAttribute($this->localKey);
    }

    /**
     * Get the fully qualified parent key name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQualifiedParentKeyName()
    {
        return $this->parent->qualifyColumn($this->localKey);
    }

    /**
     * Get the plain foreign key.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getForeignKeyName()
    {
        $segments = explode('.', $this->getQualifiedForeignKeyName());

        return end($segments);
    }

    /**
     * Get the foreign key for the relationship.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQualifiedForeignKeyName()
    {
        return $this->foreignKey;
    }

    /**
     * Get the local key for the relationship.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocalKeyName()
    {
        return $this->localKey;
    }

    public function getResults()
    {
        return ! is_null($this->getParentKey())
            ? $this->query->get()
            : $this->related->newCollection();
    }

    public function initRelation(array $models, $relation)
    {
        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $model->setRelation($relation, $this->related->newCollection());
        }

        return $models;
    }

    /**
     * Match the eagerly loaded results to their parents.
     *
     * @param  array  $models
     * @param Collection $results
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @return array
     */
    public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
    {
        if ($results->isEmpty()) {
            return $models;
        }
        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $model->setRelation($relation, call_user_func($this->condition,$model,$results));
        }
        return $models;
    }
}



To use:

Add those files to App/Relations
Add use HasCustomRelationships; to your model file
Define a relation using Callable. My questions solution:

public function noms()
    {
        return $this->toIf(Nom::class, function (self $model,Collection|Builder $results){
            if($model->show_all)
                return $results;
            return $results->where('provider_id',$model->id);
        });
    }


You could do something like this:
User model class:
<?php

class User extends Model
{
    public function noms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Nom::class);
    }

    public function allNoms()
    {
        if ($this->role === 'manager') {
            return Nom::query();
        }

        return $this->noms();
    }
}

Ps: don't forget to import necessary models in User model class like Nom class.
Controller:
class ListingController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
       return auth()->user()->allNoms()->get();
    }
}

Why this approach?

It'll be easier to filter data where ever you'll need.
Easier to maintain code and make changes in logic from one places i.e. User model class.


The relationship:
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

public function noms(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Nom::class);
}

It should be that way, no more, no less. Extra logics should be the responsibility of a different place, such as an action controller.
class NomsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->role === "manager") {
             return Nom::all();
         }

         return auth()->user()->noms()->get();
    }
}


Both returns same collection.
